# Trouble receiving POST data

Tags: post, paypal-ipn, postman

I have a aspx page that simply prints to screen whatever it receives as a POST.  The key/value pairs are passed to the Text property of a Label control and displayed as a comma-delimited string.

Here is the entire page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="System.Text" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string initialUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
        string keyString = "POST KEY-VALUE PAIRS RECEIVED: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            keyString += keys[i] + "=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[keys[i]] + ", ";
        }

        Label1.Text = keyString;
    }

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="Label"></asp:label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Google Postman to test it.  When I launch the solution in debug mode with Visual Studio 2013, then send it a post at localhost with Google Postman, it works perfectly.  The key/value pairs appear on the page.

But when I push the page out to my shared hosting (currently with GoDaddy) and then test using Google Postman, it does not work.  The page loads but the key/value pairs do not appear.

http://www.parseci.com/ipn.aspx

It seems that the POST data is not being received by the page when it's live on my GoDaddy site and I cannot figure out why.

GoDaddy technical support was no help.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: I copied the ipn.aspx file up to a privately owned server and tested with Postman as well as Chrome Advanced Rest Client.  Both worked like a charm when POSTing to the listener page on this other machine.

So I have success on one privately owned public web server, but not success with GoDaddy as host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove 'www' from the url receiving the POST.  I changed http://www.parseci.com/aspx.com to http://parseci.com/ipn.aspx and the POST arrives and is processed correctly.

For anyone having the same problem and working towards a functional Paypal IPN listener page, this solution worked with Paypal's IPN Simulator as well.  By removing 'www' from the url given to the simulator it successfully POST to my listener page for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with the Chrome Advanced Rest Client. Are you sure you are using Postman correctly and entering the parameters as form body parameters, not query params or headers?

[image: rest client screen shot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><title>
</title></head>

<body>
    <div>
        <span id="Label1">POST KEY-VALUE PAIRS RECEIVED: hello=nurse, </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: It seems this is just for debugging, but if you keep this page around, you may want to encode or sanitize the values you receive. Otherwise, your site could be vulnerable to XSS/CSRF Javascript injection-type attacks.

**EDIT**

Tried Postman too, this also works for me.

[image: Postman screen shot]

Comment: I'm not sure how to attache an image to a comment, but in Postman there are three options - 1) form-data, 2) x-www-form-urlencoded, and 3) raw.  I have tried all three to no avail.

Comment: The ultimate goal is for this page to receive a Paypal IPN.  I started out writing the page to receive and process the initial POST that comes from a Paypal IPN but I kept getting errors, so I am trying to first confirm that the page is even receiving a POST at all.  So what would be the difference between the Chrome Rest Client and what Paypal is sending?

Comment: form-data should be fine. updated with a Postman screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot.  I just now noticed your url does not have 'www'.  I removed the 'www' from my url and it worked for me as well.  Thanks.

Comment: cool. if you want the www, you can update your dns settings with godaddy so that www is aliased to your main site. be sure to use something consistent, whatever you decide on.